# Displaying circle with a center

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, geoserver

I am very much fine with creating a circle in Geoserver using st_buffer to create a view by providing latitude, longitude and radius values. It creates only a circle but without center. But I want to even see the center of the circle marked. What is to be done for this???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add the center points of your circles, you need to create a new layer in Geoserver that accesses the point information inside the PostGIS database. If you only have latitude and longitude columns there, you have to create a table/view with point geometries. ST_MakePoint() will be helpful.

Comment: But it would be better if both(circle and center point) can appear as in a single layer rather than separate layers. Is there any possibility for this??

Comment: You can combine the circle and point layers into a layer group. In OpenLayers, you only need to request the layer group then.

Comment: Oh thats a better idea. Will work on that. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered something like:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(circularstring_geometry,ST_Centroid(circularstring_geometry))',[SRID]);
```

where circularstring_geometry represents the geometry value of the circle you already created.

May be off base here -- don't know how (or if) geoserver handles collections.